# performance of wglGetProcAddress, should calls be cached?

Tags: linux, macos, winapi, opengl

There is a simple code inside a function (from a legacy library) used in init phase - for instance in a Texture Loader module.

```
loadTexture() {
    // ...
    gl_func = wglGetProcAddress(...)
    // ...
    gl_func()
}
```

Should I worry about the cost of `wglGetProcAddress`call? Or maybe it is so fast that no caching mechanism is needed? Or maybe WGL caches such calls for the process?

What about other similar functions from GLX and Apple? Should I worry or not about them as well?

Comment: Why would you *ever* write that code?

Comment: @NicolBolas I did not write it... but I have found some legacy code with a 'modern' parts of OpenGL. I am thinking about improving it without a huge refactoring.

Comment: Is this GLee in "automatic" mode, by any chance?

Comment: @Damon what's the 'automatic' mode in Glee? Unfortunately this code is legacy and no other libs (like Glee or Glew) were used.

Comment: @fen: Glee is a somewhat dated extension loader library, which could "automatically" load functions, that is, without you having to call an "init" function first (like e.g. in GLEW). This worked by having `gl_func` point to a a dummy function that looked like the one above, and changing the function pointer from dummy to real when the function was first called. It's actually not even a stupid idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wglGetProcAddress` will at least do some string comparisons so it's not free. The big issue is that your code will be ugly if you insert `wglGetProcAddress` every time you use a gl function.

It's best if you use a generator that puts all the ugly `wglGetProcAddress` in a separate file. For example using [glux](http://nixbit.com/cat/programming/libraries/glux/) or [glloadgen](https://bitbucket.org/alfonse/glloadgen/wiki/Home).

Comment: In general you advice to add some "init" method for this legacy library and in that "init" load required extensions? I would like not to include any other third party libraries (like glew or glee...)

Comment: @fen you can avoid third party libs using glloadgen. it's a script that will write the init function automatically